# How to remove white space in thumbnails

Tags: css, image

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.1 thumbnail classes for images and there is white space at the top of the images. How to remove it?
My code is:

```css
.image-thumbnail2 {
 float:left; 
 margin-bottom: 10px; 
 margin-right: 10px; 
 width: 300px; 
 padding: 0px !important;
 border-radius: 4px; 
 border: 0px;
}
.image-img-thumb2
{
 max-width:300px; 
 max-height: 220px;
 margin:0px;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 220px;
  

}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail image-thumbnail2">
  <img src="<?php echo URL::base();?>assets/images/<?php echo $val['folder'];?>/tmb/<?php echo $val['image_name'];?>" class="image-img-thumb2"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps add `display: block` to the img class

Comment: I tried this, but it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to spot the exact problem without your entire code but it seems your problem might be related to your body:

Add this to your CSS:

```
body { margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Comment: Yes, it's difficult, maybe style mixing ..Thank you all, I'll try to find the answer.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this answer (which is also mine below) @girl89 ? It does fix the problem including in the code snippet you provided.

Answer (score -1):

You should reset your margins and paddings at the top of your css:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but there is no result.